# OnActivityResult not called for an already running activity

Tags: android, android-intent, flags, onactivityresult, start-activity

I have an application with 3 layers. **A, B, C**.
A and B are fixed and C can be any one of the multiple activities.

Application normally works in A>B>C direction.
**A** calls **B** with startActivityForResult method. **B** calls **C** with startActivityForResult too and result of **C** is processed in **B** and passed back to **A** via onActivityResult methods on all layers.

It works fine but I somehow want the activity A to call C directly (where i have implemented a thread to do stuff in background) using

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.intentntfiltername.ACVITIY-C");
startActivity(i);
```

C then switches back to A by resuming it.
After this A would call B for result.
B would then call C using

```
intentName.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivityForResult(intentName, requestCodeVariable);
```

that would not create new instance of Activity C but instead resume the old activity.

The problem is when I return to B after exiting C, onActivityResult is never called. It just resumes the B activity without processing any results from C.

i.e on Activity Result is not working when we try to call an already running activity for result.

Please tell me how to implement this. Or any other workaround only if its not possible for an already running activity.

Comment: Why wouldn't C be created again? every time you from C you finish it. so at any time when you're at A or B, the instance of C is finished and doesn't exist.

Comment: No C is paused. I don't exit it after calling via A. It calls back A without exiting itself. It calls A with same FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT.

Comment: Why don't you finish it? and why are you opening an activity for result and then navigating away to a previous activity using a flag like REORDERED TO FRONT? you should re-plan your navigation more efficiently

Comment: Because this activity accessed a fingerprint capturing hardware module connected to USB port of the phone. That hardware takes 5-6 second to initialize. If I close the activity it has to be reinitialized every time I want to use hardware.
Also saving initialization state is also not an option for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

when I finish an activity that was started for a result, I call for example

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("email", email);
act.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
act.finish();
```

where the returned value I needed is the email of course, and "act" is the activity that Ive created in the onCreate as

```
act = this;
```

Comment: Yes this is what I am doing. But it is not working for the case where activity called for result was already running.

Comment: if its running, it probably wasn't closed properly previous time no? Make sure you call finish() if you want to close it

Comment: Yes it is running and I want it to keep running and resume it when I need it. It is working the way I want. It is just not returning result when I close it.